# R: how to find the quantile

Tags: r, quantile

Suppose I have a vector:

```
      x <- c(1,2,4,6,7,8)
```

And I wish to find the 10th quantile of vector x. I'm using the `quantile` function. But I am confused as if I were to pass

```
     quantile(x, c(0.1))
```

Then that would return the 10 percentile? Not necessarily the quantile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The generic function quantile produces sample quantiles corresponding
>   to the given probabilities.

See [quantile](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/quantile.html) for more description.

As mentioned [here](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~ihaka/787/lectures-quantiles-handouts.pdf), quantiles are essentially the same as percentiles, but are indexed by sample fractions rather than sample percentages.

Answer (score 3):

It's for you.

```
> quantile(x, seq(0,1, by = 0.1))
  0%  10%  20%  30%  40%  50%  60%  70%  80%  90% 100% 
 1.0  1.5  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  6.5  7.0  7.5  8.0
```